# Sharing a thread variable without making it global (Perl)

Tags: multithreading, perl, scope, lexical-scope

I'm trying to write a simple script that uses threads and shares a variable, but I don't want to make this variable global to the whole script.  Below is a simplified example.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use threads;
use threads::shared;

my $val:shared;

# Create threads
for my $i (1 .. 5) {
    threads->create(\&do_something, $i);
}

# Wait for all threads to complete
map { $_->join(); } threads->list();

# $val is global to the script so this line will work!
print "VAL IS: $val\n";

sub do_something {
    my $i = shift;
    print "Doing something with thread $i!\n";

    {
        lock $val;
        $val = "SOMETHING IS $i";
        print "$val\n\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

> Doing something with thread 1!
>   SOMETHING IS 1
>
> Doing something with thread 2!
>   SOMETHING IS 2
>
> Doing something with thread 3!
>   SOMETHING IS 3
>
> Doing something with thread 4!
>   SOMETHING IS 4
>
> Doing something with thread 5!
>   SOMETHING IS 5
>
> VAL IS: SOMETHING IS 5

---

How can I get this effect without making `$val` accessible to the whole script?  In other words, how can I make it so attempting to print `VAL IS: $val` will fail, but the variable will still be successfully shared by the threads?

---

I can't define it like this:

```
# Create threads
for my $i (1 .. 5) {
    my $val:shared;
    threads->create(\&do_something, $i);
}
```

Or I will get:

> Global symbol "$val" requires explicit package

***What is the right way to lexically scope a shared variable?***

Comment: Unless you're passing it in, how could a thread both be shared (global) and not global?  What it seems like you want to do is create a layer for your scope.  Also did you try using `our($val);`?

Comment: Side-note, `map { $_->join(); } threads->list();` => `$_->join() for threads->list();` to keep your intentions clear.

Comment: @Сухой27, thanks that is a bit clearer.

Comment: @vol7ron, defining `$val` using `our` would make it even MORE global.  I just want the shared variable to be accessible only by the threads and nowhere else.

Comment: It exposes it to the package, but perhaps that's what you want. I'm a little preoccupied, so I shouldn't have commented, but this might fall into the "what have you tried?" category

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pass a reference to it as an argument.

```
sub do_something {
   my ($id, $lock_ref) = @_;
   print("$id: Started\n");
   {
      lock $$lock_ref;
      print("$id: Exclusive\n");
      sleep(1);
   }
   print("$id: done.\n");
}

{
   my $lock :shared;
   for my $id (1..5) {
      async { do_something($id, \$lock); };
   }
}
```

Or scope it so only the worker subs can see it.

```
{
   my $lock :shared;

   sub do_something {
      my ($id) = @_;
      print("$id: Started\n");
      {
         lock $lock;
         print("$id: Exclusive\n");
         sleep(1);
      }
      print("$id: done.\n");
   }
}

for my $id (1..5) {
   async { do_something($id); };
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can limit the scope of shared variable (make sure that perl sees shared variable before thread creation),

```
# ..
{
  my $val:shared;
  sub do_something {
      my $i = shift;
      print "Doing something with thread $i!\n";

      {
          lock $val;
          $val = "SOMETHING IS $i";
          print "$val\n\n";
      }
  }
}

# Create threads
for my $i (1 .. 5) {
    threads->create(\&do_something, $i);
}

# ...
```