# Per: Visibility of variables of a subroutines for its subroutine

Tags: perl, subroutine

I have a problem about variables of a subroutine which cannot be accessed by another subroutine.

the first subroutine :

```
sub esr_info {
    my $esr ;
    my @vpls = () ;
    my @sap = ();
    my @spoke = () ;
    &conf_esr($esr , 1);
}
```

the second :

```
sub conf_esr {
     my $e = @_[0] ;
     some code (@vpls, @sap, @spoke);
}
```

the first calls the second, and I need the variables of the first to be local and not global for the whole code (for threading purposes). The second uses all the variables of the first . I get these errors :

> Global symbol "$esr" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $esr"?) at w.pl line 63.
>
> Global symbol "@vpls" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my @vpls"?) at w.pl line 74.

My question : Can a subroutine access the vars of another without declaring those vars as global ?

Many thanks for reading the post.

Comment: If you are using the code in with [threads](https://perldoc.perl.org/threads.html) please show the relevant code

Comment: See also [Sharing a thread variable without making it global](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33020623/2173773)

Comment: Tip: `my @a = ();` is a weird way of writing `my @a;`

Answer (score 1):

You can contain (restrict the visibility of) the variables to the two subs by introducing a scope `{ ... }`, for example:

```
{ 
    my $esr ;
    my @vpls = () ;
    my @sap = ();
    my @spoke = () ;

    sub esr_info {
        conf_esr($esr , 1);
    }

    sub conf_esr {
        my $e = @_[0] ;
        #some code (@vpls, @sap, @spoke);
    }
}
```

But note that the variables now retain the values after the subs are exited (they become state variables). This is also called a closure.

But other approaches could be more appropriate (closures can make the code more difficult to read and hence to maintain) depending on you situation. For example, alternatives could be:

- you could pass references to the variables as arguments to `conf_esr`, or better
- use an object oriented approach where the variables are contained in a `$self` hash.

Comment: Thank you Håkon for your answer,

So if I use a scope, I wouldn't be able to thread those subs, wright ? Since, the variables will get all mixed up in different processes. Especially that not both subs are threadded in the same way.

If not, I will pass vars in the arguments of the sub.

Comment: You are welcome! I am not sure what exactly you mean by *"threadded"*.. Note that lexical variables in [threads](https://perldoc.perl.org/threads.html) are separate, unless you [declare them as shared](https://perldoc.perl.org/threads/shared.html). Please clarify what you are trying to do

Answer (score 0):

> My question : Can a subroutine access the vars of another without declaring those vars as global ?

No. You should try passing in variables, it's better form, but you can also use global variables.

```
my $i=1;
mysub(); # This will not change the global $i
print "i=$i\n"; # This should print '1'
exit;

##########
sub mysub
{my $i=2; # This is a variable local to mysub() only.
return;
}
```

Type in the code above and run it with Perl. Notice that the $i in the subroutine `mysub()` is completely different than the global $i in the program itself, because the $i in the `mysub()` is a different memory address.

Now let's change $i to global. `mysub()` will change the global $i because it doesn't have a local $i declared.

```
my $i=1;
mysub(); # This will not change the global $i
print "i=$i\n"; # This should print '2'
exit;

##########
sub mysub
{$i=2; # This is changing the value in the global $i memory area. 
return;
}
```

Comment: Okay, got it. I passed the arguments to the subroutine. Long work but works fine.
Thanks a lot